# pyparsing infixNotation optimization

Tags: python, pyparsing, infix-notation

My implementation of `infixNotation` is running slower than I would like even after  using `enablePackrat`, which greatly increased performance.

Parsing needs to recognize and parse the following types of strings:

- Basic arithmetic operations, numbers, negation, and parentheses groupings
- Groupings in the format `prefix::dotted.alphanum.string -> [prefix::dotted.alphanum.string]`
- Strings that look like function calls e.g. `pow(some::var + 2.3, 5) -> [pow, [[some::var, +, 2.3], 5]]`

The code I'm using:

```
def parse_expression(expr_str):

    fraction = Combine("." + Word(nums))
    number = Combine(Word(nums) + Optional(fraction)).setParseAction(str_to_num)

    event_id_expr = Word(alphanums + "_") + "::"
    dotted_columns = Combine(Word(alphanums + "_") + Optional("."))

    column_expr = Combine(event_id_expr + OneOrMore(dotted_columns))

    arith_expr = infixNotation(column_expr | number, [
        (Word(alphanums + "_"), 1, opAssoc.RIGHT),
        ("-", 1, opAssoc.RIGHT),
        (oneOf("* /"), 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
        (oneOf("+ -"), 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
        (Literal(","), 2, opAssoc.LEFT)
    ])

    parsed_expr = arith_expr.parseString(expr_str).asList()[0]

    return parsed_expr

 def str_to_num(t):
      num_str = t[0]
      try:
          return int(num_str)
      except ValueError:
          return float(num_str)
```

Are there any changes I can make that would result in substantial performance improvements?  The structures I'm parsing are fairly simple, but they're in batches.  On average each string is taking ~5.3ms.

Comment: Replace `number` with `pyparsing_common.number`. It will convert to int or float as appropriate, just as your `str_to_num` parse action does, but more importantly, it uses a single Regex to do the parse instead of series of smaller expressions wrapped in a Combine. I've found that this simple change can make a measureable performance difference.

Comment: Great. That alone shaved off ~.5ms

Comment: You may be approaching the limit - pyparsing's virtue is not in runtime speed.

Comment: I seem to be late to the party here, but wouldn't it be faster to build the pyparsing expression out of the loop and then call parseString on the built expression in the loop? It might be fast to create the grammar, but might still save a few ticks to do it separately.

Comment: @user3747260 mind sharing what exactly does this do? I tried playing around but couldn't understand much. I'm trying to write a parser that identifies custom variables (using double curly braces) and was wondering if this could be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are "fudging" the functions as if they are operators, I think you are better off moving function calls into the operand expression for `infixNotation`:

```
def parse_expression(expr_str):

    number = pyparsing_common.number()

    event_id_expr = Word(alphas+"_", alphanums + "_") + "::"
    dotted_columns = Combine(Word(alphas+"_", alphanums + "_") + Optional("."))

    column_expr = Combine(event_id_expr + OneOrMore(dotted_columns))

    func_name = Word(alphas+"_", alphanums+'_')
    LPAR, RPAR = map(Suppress, "()")
    arith_expr = Forward()
    func_call = Group(func_name('name') 
                      + LPAR 
                      + Group(Optional(delimitedList(arith_expr)))("args") 
                      + RPAR)

    arith_expr <<= infixNotation(number | func_call | column_expr, [
        ("-", 1, opAssoc.RIGHT),
        (oneOf("* /"), 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
        (oneOf("+ -"), 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
    ])

    parsed_expr = arith_expr.parseString(expr_str)[0]

    return parsed_expr
```

I also modified most of your identifiers to use the two-argument form of Word - just using `Word(alphanums+"_")` would also match ordinary integers, which I don't *think* is your intent. If I got this wrong, then just put these back as you had them.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  This brought it down to about ~3.8ms and also made the logic for my token handling simpler.